# Let parent process return before child process using python multiprocessing library

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When one creates Processes with multiprocessing library from python, the parent process waits for its children to return before it returns. In fact, the documentation recommends joining all children.
But I would like to let the parent return *before* its child process finish.

Is there any way to "detach" the child process.

I know that using subprocess.Popen it is possible to create detached child processes, but i would like to use the features from multiprocessing library, like Queues, Locks and so.

I made two examples to show the difference.

The first example uses the multiprocessing library. When this script is called, it prints the parent message, waits 5 seconds, prints the child message and only then return.

```
# Using multiprocessing, only returns after 5 seconds
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep, asctime

def child():
    sleep(5.0)
    print 'Child end reached on', asctime()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Process(target = child)
    p.start()
    # Detach child process here so parent can return.
    print 'Parent end reached on', asctime()
```

The second example uses the subprocess.Popen. When this script is called, it prints the parent message, returns (!!!) and after 5 seconds prints the child message.

```
# Using Popen, returns immediately.
import sys
from subprocess import Popen
from time import sleep, asctime

def child():
    sleep(5)
    print 'Child end reached on', asctime()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if 'call_child' in sys.argv:
        child()
    else:
        Popen([sys.executable] + [__file__] + ['call_child'])
        print 'Parent end reached on', asctime()
```

The second example would be acceptable if I could pass Queues, Pipes, Locks, Semaphores, etc..

IMO, the first example also leads to a more cleaner code.

I'm using python 2.7 on Windows.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't send the desired value via a pipe or Queue _without_ ending the parent process?

Comment: There are several interprocess messaging libraries, like pyzmq that you could use from the "parent" process.  I am not familiar with their details, but they no doubt have ways of managing the transmission and receipt of messages in a thread-secure (or async) way.  I imagine you want to be able to start and stop the parent process at will from time to time to inspect the running child processes?  I think a messaging system will be better for this than multiprocessing.

Comment: I want to let the parent process end because I want my program to perform a set of tasks in the background and letting user (or a calling script) to continue interacting with the command prompt. In this set of tasks, it would be very interesting to have queues and pipes shared between children processes.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the process object from the _children set of the current process object, the the parent process will exit immediately.

Theh multiprocessing module manages child processes in a private set and join them when the current process exits. You can remove children from the set if you don't care of them.

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc_main)
multiprocessing.current_process()._children.discard(process)
exit(0)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: '_MainProcess' object has no attribute '_children'`