# How to avoid parent from waiting for child in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm fairly new to python multiprocessing, and I am trying to write a class that is able to asynchronously execute functions and attached callbacks.

First of all, let's settle a common nomenclature for this specific problem:

```
┬─ process1 (parent)
└─┬─ process2 (child of parent1)
  └─── process3 (child of parent2)
```

After documenting me a bit on the subject, and following [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640276/let-parent-process-return-before-child-process-using-python-multiprocessing-libr), in order to do so, I've come up with the following code for the `run` method:

```py
import multiprocessing


class AsyncProcess:
    def __init__(self, target, callback=None, args=(), kwargs={}):
        self._target = target
        self._callback = callback
        self._args = args
        self._kwargs = kwargs
        self._process = None

    def run(self):
        def wrapper():
            return_value = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

            if self._callback is not None:
                process = multiprocessing.Process(target=self._callback, args=(return_value,))
                process.start()
                multiprocessing.process._children.discard(process)

        self._process = multiprocessing.Process(target=wrapper)
        self._process.start()
```

The `AsyncProcess` class is bigger than this (it is intended to work as an adapter between `multiprocessing.Process` and `subprocess.Popen` for executing both external processes and python functions in new processes); that's why it is not a subclass of `multiprocessing.Process` and is instead just using it (in case anyone wondered).

What I'm trying to achieve here is to be able to launch a child process (`process3`) from within another process (`process2`) without it (`process2`) having to wait for the child process (`process3`) (since it may take way longer for the child to finish than for the parent). The `daemon` attribute of `multiprocessing.Process` is not useful since, when the parent process dies (`process2`), the child process (`process3`) is killed too (and I just want to leave it running until it finishes).

There is, however, two things I don't like at all about the solution I've come up with:

1. I'm tinkering with the internals of `multiprocessing`, which I don't like a bit.
2. Since I'm erasing the child process (`process3`) from the children pool of the parent (`process2`), I'm guessing that leaves the poor child orphan (which I don't really know what exactly implies but most certainly is no good practice at all).

The thing here is **how can I achieve the parent not waiting for the children without actually killing the children nor falling into orphan processes**? Is there any other, more correct or more elegant way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

I was thinking about assigning the child process (`process3`) to the parent of the process that spawned this child process (`process1`), i.e. the grandparent of the child process (which I know will be alive for sure), but I haven't found a way to actually do that.

---

**Some clarifications**:

1. `Popen` does what I want to achieve, but it only does it with external processes, i.e. I cannot execute a python function with all the context by using `Popen` (that I know, of course).
2. Using `os.fork` had come to mind, but I find the way of distinguishing parent vs. child code a bit cumbersome (handling `PID == 0` and `PID != 0` cases, etc.).
3. I haven't thought about any solutions using the `threading` package since I wanted to manage processes, not threads, and leave thread management to the OS.
4. Starting `process3` from `process1` directly solves the problem of orphan processes, but then I have to do an active polling on `process1` in order to know when `process2` finishes, which is actually not an option (`process1` manages a server that cannot be blocked).
5. I need `process2` to finish as soon as possible in order to get some data from it; that's why I'm not executing the content of `process3` directly inside `process2`.

---

**Something I came up with while writing the question**:

Since my problem is having to launch `process3` from within `process2` and launching it from `process1` solves the problem but active polling on `process1` is not an option, I could also launch `process2` and `process3` from within `process1` at the same time, passing the `process2` object to `process3` and perform the active polling on `process3` with a small interval to ensure quick response after `process2` finished.

Does this have any sense or is it an over complicated solution for something that is already solved (and that I don't know of)?

Comment: Although i dont really understand why you need 2 child processes, but theoretically spoken: What about producer/consumer pattern (and a Queue) to separate the dependency between process1 and the others ? To notify a parent process you could make use of the Publish–subscribe pattern.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I need them because `process1` cannot do anything else than spawning new processes, `process2` needs to end as early as possible (since I need the exit code of the process available as soon as possible for other purposes) and `process3` is intended for executing the proper callback of `process2`.

Maybe my entire way of thinking about this problem is just not correct; I'll take a look at your suggestions to see if they fit my purposes.

Comment: Could you please state what are you trying to achieve from a higher point of view? Nesting children processes is hardly a good idea as long as there is not a really specific use case.

Comment: @noxdafox I would need exactly the following:

 1. The main process needs to execute some work asynchronously.
 2. In order to process the result of that asynchronous work, I need a callback to execute right after the asynchronous work, but separate from it because I need the asynchronous work process to end as soon as possible to collect its exit code.

Now that I think about it, anyway, I might be wrong at trying to capture the exit code of the child process that quickly. Simply running the callback inside the same process and passing the code as parameter should be clean enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do (ignoring the question of whether it is a good idea) is not possible with the multiprocessing library without the kind of tinkering with the internals that you want to avoid, precisely because the multiprocessing library is *designed specifically* for child processes that do not outlive the parent.

I think the answer is indeed to use `subprocess.Popen()`, although that will mean foregoing the nice high-level API of the multiprocessing library. No, you can't execute a Python function directly but you can create a separate script.py to call the function you want.